# Select Options not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript

I have followed [this](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2013/12/come-implementare-in-rails-4-delle-dropdown-dipendenti-con-script-jquery-non-intrusivo/) tutorial to get a dependant select form working in Rails 4.

I can confirm that a AJAX request is being fired and successfully returns child results upon selecting a value from my parent select input. Both Firebug and manual entry of the requested url confirms this. Manual routing to the URL returns this:

```
{"rule_attributes":[{"id":2,"human_name":"Age"},{"id":1,"human_name":"Gender"}]}
```

My form code (using simple_form & haml):

```
= f.input :rule_attribute_id,
            :collection => [],
            :label_method => :human_name , 
            :value_method => :id,
            :input_html => {"data-option-dependent" => true,"data-option-observed" => "rule_model_dropdown","data-option-url" => "/rule_models/:rule_model_id:/rule_attributes.json","data-option-key-method" => :id,"data-option-value-method" => :human_name}
```

This is my coffeescript code that should take care of child option population from the json result:

```
  if observed.val()
    url = url_mask.replace(regexp, observed.val())

    $.getJSON url, (data) ->
      $.each data, (i, object) ->
        observer.append $("<option>").attr("value", object[key_method]).text(object[value_method])
        observer.attr "disabled", false
```

In the case listed above, I'm expecting the child  to have Age and Gender as Options (As per JSON). For some reason the values are not populated as options and the child  remains with no options.

Can anybody help with what I'm doing wrong and how to get the child  to populate with the data passed by JSON?

**UPDATE**

Additional methods in my js looks like this:

```
observer_dom_id = $(this).attr("id")
observed_dom_id = $(this).data("option-observed")
url_mask = $(this).data("option-url")
key_method = $(this).data("option-key-method")
value_method = $(this).data("option-value-method")
```

**UPDATE 2**
This is the complete js file:

```
$ ->
  $("select[data-option-dependent=true]").each (i) ->
observer_dom_id = $(this).attr("id")
observed_dom_id = $(this).data("option-observed")
url_mask = $(this).data("option-url")
key_method = $(this).data("option-key-method")
value_method = $(this).data("option-value-method")
prompt = $("<option value=\"\">").text("Select a value")
regexp = /:[0-9a-zA-Z_]+:/g
observer = $("select#" + observer_dom_id)
observed = $("#" + observed_dom_id)

observer.attr "disabled", true  if not observer.val() and observed.size() > 1

observed.on "change", ->
  observer.empty().append prompt

  if observed.val()
    url = url_mask.replace(regexp, observed.val())

    $.getJSON url, (data) ->
      $.each data, (i, object) ->
        # console.log(data)
        observer.append $("<option>").attr("value", object[key_method]).text(object[value_method])
        observer.attr "disabled", false
```

Comment: What does your `key_method` look like?

Comment: did you check your data object to see if there is actually data in there? Also I noticed you are appending the '<option>' to the observer, are you transferring this to your 'select' object

Comment: @progrAmmar , this is a newbie question but how do I check the value of the data object? Also I'm not sure if the object is transferred to the 'select'. The coffeescript segment displayed above is the last section of my javascript code. Do I need to add anything in there?

Comment: I don't know about coffeescript but the browsers these days come equipped with debugging consoles (specifically for client script). When you Press F12 on your browser it will show you the debugging controls. You can check the data values in the console but posting console.log (this is what I do in JavaScript) so if I do console.log(data) it will show me what my data contains.

Comment: @progrAmmar when I add console.dir(data) to my JS code, it outputs the following to the console log:  [Object { id=2, human_name="Age"}, Object { id=1, human_name="Gender"}]. So I assume that the object is being populated correctly.

Comment: Great it means the data is fine. Please check what is the 'observer' referring to. This data should be appended to your dropdown

Comment: @progrAmmar , I will check this. I have updated my question with the code snippet that sets the observer.

Comment: @progrAmmar , I have added console.log(observer) to my js and it confirms that the ID of my <select> tag is generated correctly as Object[select#credit_rule_rule_attribute_id.select.required]

Comment: Try this
 $.each data, (i, object) ->
   var opt = new Option(object[key_method]).text, (object[value_method])
    observer.append(opt)

Comment: @progrAmmar , This reaults in an error stating that I cannot use the word "var". I am using Coffeescript so I guess this causes the issue. Any idea how I'd go about translating the above into an acceptable Coffee syntax?

Comment: $.each data, (object, i) ->
  opt = new Option((object[key_method]).text, object[value_method])
  observer.append opt

This will be your coffee script